# How do I implement separator in a dataset loaded directly from sklearn library?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I know how to use separator (sep ="") when importing the dataset using pd.read_csv

but I don't know what to use to implement the separator on a dataset loaded from sklearn itself, like the digits dataset i used below where i want to implement the \n separator.

code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import pandas as pd
df = load_digits()
print(df)
```

[image: see here]

Comment: Please read how to properly ask questions and provide code, so that it is easier for the community to help you. For example, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at carefully, you'll see that `load_digits` is a dictionary. You can reach its elements by

```
df.keys()
```

which returns

```
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'frame', 'feature_names', 'target_names', 'images', 'DESCR'])
```

So, if you want to get the data, just call the `data` key

```
df['data']
```

returns

```
[[ 0.  0.  5. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0. ... 10.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ... 16.  9.  0.]
 ...
 [ 0.  0.  1. ...  6.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2. ... 12.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 10. ... 12.  1.  0.]]
```